# Temporarily disable of zoom levels configuration in free drive/navigation

Tags: android, skmaps

I try to use zoom levels config like this:

```
SKZoomLevelConfiguration[] zoomLevelConfigurations = new SKZoomLevelConfiguration[]{
        new SKZoomLevelConfiguration(0, 10, 16.5f),
        new SKZoomLevelConfiguration(10, 40, 16f),
        new SKZoomLevelConfiguration(40, 70, 15f),
        new SKZoomLevelConfiguration(70, 150, 14.5f),
};
navigationSettings.setZoomLevelConfigurations(zoomLevelConfigurations);
navigationManager.startNavigation(navigationSettings);
```

Its working good. But in some cases i need to disable this auto-changes of zoom (for example, if user press zoom out or zoom in - we need to fixate selected by user zoom for next few seconds).

How can i disable this configuration without stop/start navigation?

Also, second question - how can i change duration for zoom levels configuration animation?

SDK version 2.5.1

Comment: we'll check with the dev team if it's possible

Answer (score 1):

1) To disable the auto-changes of the zoom level:
An example can be found in the demo project: Car navigation UI -> Calculate routes -> Start navigation -> Pan/zoom -> Map follower mode is set to SKMapSettings.SKMapFollowerMode.NONE_WITH_HEADING -> Press back button -> Map is set in navigation mode

Pressing zoom out or zoom in onActionZoom() method is called:

```
@Override 
public void onActionZoom() { 
   // switch to panning mode 
    SKMapSettings mapSettings = mapView.getMapSettings(); 
    mapSettings.setInertiaPanningEnabled(true); 
    mapSettings.setMapZoomingEnabled(true); 
    mapSettings.setMapRotationEnabled(true); 
    mapView.getMapSettings().setFollowerMode(SKMapSettings.SKMapFollowerMode.NONE_WITH_HEADING); 
    mapView.getMapSettings().setMapDisplayMode(SKMapSettings.SKMapDisplayMode.MODE_2D); 
}
```

Note: The auto-changes of zoom works only in SKMapSettings.SKMapDisplayMode.MODE_2D.

2) To change the duration for zoom levels configuration: this feature is not supported for the moment